# Can you get to a command line on the G1 phone?

Tags: android

I understand the Android OS is based on Linux. Does that mean the G1 phone has a terminal emulator and you can open a console and use commands like `cd`, `ls`, etc? Or failing that, would it be possible to write a terminal emulator for it?

On a related note, would it be possible to run a ssh server on the G1 and log into it over a wifi connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, until recently [everything you typed on the keyboard got echoed to a root shell](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Burnette/?p=680). Nasty bug.

That said, you want [PTerminal](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f28/how-to-pterminal-6485/), from the Android Market.

As for SSH, yep. You can [even install Debian on the phone](http://www.saurik.com/id/10).

Comment: Ahem, that bug was around for like 2 days. Also, I tried it on my phone on RC29 and it didn't work (the bug wasn't present).

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are a few terminal emulators in the market and elseware on the web (quick google search and you'll see), but if you are running the latest OS patch level (RC30) you will no longer be able to get root at all.  The shell's are still somewhat useful to poke around the file system and see the results of ps and top for example.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know, it's worth pointing out that android has a fairly secure application sandbox. Each installed app runs as it's own user. Not many binaries on the phone are world-executable, and a lot of files aren't even world-readable.

However, I don't think anything is preventing you from copying executables to the phone and running them as a non-privileged user.

Answer (score 0):

The android SDK comes with a tool that lets you run a shell from your development machine over USB.  The su command does not work on the TMobile phone but does work on the unlocked phone that comes direct from google.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to flash back to RC29 and get root, I did and have Terminal Emulator running good. I just don't know many commands.